# introductory video on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-systems

Is there a great first video for someone that has no idea about operating systems to introduce them to the possibility of using Ubuntu, demonstrating what it looks like, advantages / disadvantages, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll like the [Ubuntu Screencasts](http://screencasts.ubuntu.com/). They give you a good look at what Ubuntu has to offer. A great one for you to start out with is the [Introduction to Ubuntu](http://screencasts.ubuntu.com/MoS2007/01_Ubuntu).

The video is more of an overview of Ubuntu and the philosophy. For something more geared towards advantages and disadvantages, take a look at the article on the Ubuntu site: [Strengths and Weaknesses](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Strengths_and_weaknesses). There is also [this article](http://techtipster.wordpress.com/2007/11/20/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-linux/) which sums some things up, although not entirely accurate, so I'd suggest reading into the comments.